# How to specify custom --rulesdir for eslint in vim editor

Tags: javascript, vim, eslint

I have installed [syntastic plugin](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) in vim and installed eslint in npm globally. Below is the snippet of my .vimrc for syntastic configuration:

```
set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*

let g:syntastic_javascript_checkers = ["eslint"]
let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0
```

Here's the result when I run :SyntasticInfo javascript,

```
Syntastic version: 3.6.0-64 (Vim 704, CYGWIN_NT-6.3)
Info for filetype: javascript
Global mode: active
Filetype javascript is active
Available checker: eslint
Currently enabled checker: eslint
```

Assume I have following project structure, there're some custom rules activated in `.eslintrc`, and the definition of those rules are in `.eslintrules` dir:

```
xxx_project:
   |--.eslintrc
   |--.eslintrules
        |-- rule1.js
        |-- rule2.js
        |-- ...
   |-- src
        |-- abc.js
```

Everytime I run :SyntasticCheck on some source file, nothing happens. So I try running eslint against some js file directly in command line. There're some errors threw indicating cannot find definition of some custom rules.

So I think eslint has found the configuration file, but it doesn't know where the --rulesdir is.

Can someone help here? As far as I know, the --rulesdir option is only available in command line.

Comment: Did you try running `eslint` directly?

Comment: Turn on debugging to find out what's going on: `:let g:syntastic_debug=3`, run the checker, then run `:mes`.  If you can't figure it out post to the [issue tracker](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues).

Comment: @romainl, I tried running eslint directly, there's an error: Cannot find definition of xxx rule.  The problem is there're some custom rules in .eslintrc and eslint can't find the definition of them. I searched around, I find that eslint command line can have the option --rulesdir to specify the custom rules directory.  But vim is running eslint checker, I don't know how to let vim to tell eslint the correct rules directory for this project. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 6):

Edit:

```
function! ESLintArgs()
    let rules = findfile('.eslintrules', '.;')
    return rules != '' ? '--rulesdir ' . shellescape(fnamemodify(rules, ':p:h')) : ''
endfunction

autocmd FileType javascript let b:syntastic_javascript_eslint_args = ESLintArgs()
```

This tries to find a file named `.eslintrules` and sets `--ruledir` to its base directory.

Comment: hi, I don't want to put it in the .vimrc, because for every project, the --rulesdir path could be different.

Comment: That's very nice, if I want to inline some rules directly in my `.vimrc`, how should I do ?